# Deserialize JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a json in which there is a string in the string that stores the json object, it has unescaped quotes. What should I do about it? Maybe there is some kind of regex that will replace quotes with escaped ones. There are also strings that store text containing words in quotes. I need to decode it in Java.

```
"text":"[options="header", cols=".^6,^.^4, ^4,^.^4,^.^3"] ",
"entity":"some text "some text" "
```

Comment: If it has unescaped quotes, it's not JSON. You can try to turn it into valid JSON, but you'd have to guess which quotes should be escaped.